# How to retrieve and use data from Firebase snapshot after creating postDict; i get "0\0\0"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've looked at several questions and examples, but to no avail. The approach I'm taking to display an array of posts "should work" from what I'm seeing, but for some reason I can't access a key/value pair inside my snapshot data...

In the below code I'm able to create the postDict and I see all the data I need, however I'm unable to assign the userID value, instead of the string value coming through I see the following in the debug console:
userID = (String) "\0\0\0"

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
static func allPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

    postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]
            else { return completion([]) }

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        var posts = [Post]()

        for postSnap in snapshot {

            guard let postDict = postSnap.value as? [String : AnyObject],
                let userID = postDict["userID"] as? String

                else { continue }

            dispatchGroup.enter()

            PostFirebase.getPostByKey(postKey: postSnap.key, userID: userID, completion: { (post) in
                if let post = post {
                    posts.append(post)

                    print("posts array = \(posts)")
                }

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            completion(posts.reversed())
        })
    })
}
```

Here is the JSON Export from `/posts`:

```
{
  "Tzgb6023LzYV8lVJr3KHbosdtR72" : {
    "-LQEw9M7DPZ0XugHdd7e" : {
      "noCount" : 0,
      "photoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...",
      "postText" : "soAwesome",
      "timestamp" : 5.62779748747864E8,
      "userID" : "Tzgb6023LzYV8lVJr3KHbosdtR72",
      "userPhotoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/....",
      "username" : "ninjaone ",
      "videoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/....",
      "voteCount" : 2,
      "yesCount" : 2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the JSON at `/posts` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just added the JSON at posts. let me know if this helps, thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the JSON it seems that you have two dynamic levels under `/posts`. My guess is that the first level is the UID of the user who made the post, while the level under that is the post ID (generated by calling `childByAutoId`).

Your code however only loops over the first level (the UIDs) and then tries to read posts. That won't work of course, because there's another dynamic level under. So you'll need two (nested) loops:

```
let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]
        else { return completion([]) }

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    var posts = [Post]()

    for userSnap in snapshot {
      guard let postSnapshots = userSnap.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]

      for postSnap in postSnapshots {

        guard let postDict = postSnap.value as? [String : AnyObject],
            let userID = postDict["userID"] as? String

            else { continue }

        dispatchGroup.enter()

        PostFirebase.getPostByKey(postKey: postSnap.key, userID: userID, completion: { (post) in
            if let post = post {
                posts.append(post)

                print("posts array = \(posts)")
            }

            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
      }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
        completion(posts.reversed())
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me unstuck! It seems painfully obvious now, but I couldn't see the need for an additional loop. You da man!